# How to add dynamic content on all pages in virto commerce?

Tags: shopify, virtocommerce

When we are using marketing tab from front end for make the home page dynamic. How to use this dynamic content(placeholder) for other pages in Virto Commerce?

Comment: Use the same placeholder with another place ID that doesn't suit you? ```<vc-content-place id="Other place identifier></vc-content-place>```

Comment: ok thanks...this exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

In order to add an advertising spot via Marketing Module, the user should first prepare the dynamic content infrastructure and go through the following steps:

- Create a content item.
- Create a content placeholder.
- Create a content publishing.
  Once the Dynamic content infrastructure is prepared, the user should add the dynamic content to a web site:

```
<vc-content-place id="Right banner 240x400" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 rightblock"></vc-content-place>
```

The user should open the web page HTML file;
Insert the code into the HTML file. The ID is the placeholder name :

In order to add a real advertising content, the user should do the following:

Open Marketing Module:

1. Select ‘Dynamic content’ tab;
2. Select ‘Content items’;
3. Select a specific content item from the list, to which the advertising content will be applied;

Insert the code into HTML text box and save the changes;
The new content will appear immediately on the web page.

Learn more on [Open-source ASP.NET Software for B2B eCommerce](https://virtocommerce.com/) and [Virto Commerce](https://github.com/virtocommerce) and [How to add Advertising Spot](https://docs.virtocommerce.org/modules/marketing/#add-advertising-spot)